# bootstrap thumbnail and horizontal scroll bar in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with bootstrap thumbnail and horizontal scrollbar in IE and Firefox but not chrome nor mobile browsers.

So basically, in firefox and IE the modals look strange and there is a horizontal scroll bar, however this issue does not appear in chrome or mobile phone browsers. as you see in the image, this is the issue

[image: webpage looks in firefox]

and this is how modals look like in **firefox** 
[image]
and this is how it should look like without any issue as in **chrome**
[image]

and for the modal code here:

```
<div class="container" id="portfolio" >
          <hr>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                         <div class="thumbnail">
                             <a href="Text 101 WebBuild V1/Text 101 WebBuild V1.html" target="_blank">  <img src="images/text101.png" alt="..." class="image">
                                <div class="imgDescription">
                                     <h3 class="img-content"><strong>Text 101</strong></h3>
                                     <span class="modal-button" >
                                     <img src="images/unity1.png" style="height:30px; width:30px;" >    </span>                                         
                               </div>       
                              </a>

                         </div>
                     </div>

                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                         <div class="thumbnail">
                             <a href="landingPage.html"  target="_blank">  <img src="images/myweb-app.png" alt="..." class="image">
                                <div class="imgDescription">
                                     <h3 class="img-content" style="left:95px;"><strong>MyWebsite App</strong></h3>
                                     <span class="modal-button" style="left:145px">
                                     <img src="images/webdev.png" style="height:30px; width:auto;" >    </span> 

                               </div>       
                                </a>
                         </div>
                     </div>




                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                         <div class="thumbnail">
                             <a href="#">  <img src="images/card3.jpg" alt="..." class="image">
                                <div class="imgDescription">
                                     <h3 class="img-content"></h3>
                                     <span class="modal-button"></span>


                               </div>       
                                </a> 
                         </div>
                     </div>

        </div>  <!-- portfolio end here -->
```

and the css used here:

```
.thumbnail {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;

            }
            .thumbnail .imgDescription {
                position: absolute;
                top: 4px;
                left: 4px;
                width: 98%;
                height: 96%;
                display: none;
                color: #FFF;
                 -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
                -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;

            }
            .thumbnail:hover .imgDescription {
                display: block;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
            }

            .thumbnail .imgDescription .img-content {
                position: absolute;
                top: 25%;
                left:35%;
                color:white;    
                }

        .thumbnail .imgDescription .modal-button {
            position: absolute;
                top: 55%;
                left:43%;
        }
```

I just couldn't figure where the issue is I mean it runs noraml in chrome and phone browsers. any help with be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? There were some changes dealing with modals and scroll bars in recent releases. Try updating to the most recent version.

Comment: i am using 3.3.6, i assume it's the latest one as the fourth still beta version if not mistaken

Comment: Yes, that is the latest. Is the site accessible so we can look at the code? My best guess is something in the modal is causing the issue and not the actual modal. Make sure the HTML is valid and all tags are closed. Also check css of modal elements, maybe you have -webkit- styles not applied to other browsers. Hard to debug without code.

Comment: the site is accessible, so should i post a link to the site or should i post the modal codes that i used

Comment: A link to the site would be best.

Comment: here is the link http://malikgabroun.com/

Comment: I can't trigger the modal opening. Looks like the images at the bottom should trigger it due to the class `modal-button` but you don't have any JavaScript on the page besides bootstrap and jquery core libraries. Can you get the modal working again? You also have a misplaced `</a>` inside the `modal-button`, it should be two tags down after the `</span>` and `</div>`. If you view the page source in Firefox it turns invalid HTML tags red.

Comment: yeah, i just notice the misplaced tags and fixed them but even with that the modal still not working in firefox and IE but working fine in chrome, the modal-button is for positioning purposes.

Comment: The modal does not work in any browser because there is no JavaScript to trigger the modal opening, it just opens a new tab. You need to add the JavaScript that opens the modal.

Comment: but you can see clearly in the chrome highlighted picture that the modal appear and works fine unlike the firefox. and if i assume that as suggested need to add script in order to make it work, how?

Comment: I don't see a modal in any of your screen shots. Here is what a modal looks like: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals. I think you are not even using or talking about modals... The page looks fine in Firefox but in IE it does look bad. You still have not fixed the HTML I pointed out which is probably the issue with IE. I will post an answer with fixed HTML

Comment: sorry i kept saying modal, that was in a different project, i am talking about thumbnails in this one, the issue if you look at the chrome shot the thumbnails working fine but in firefox are not. and I am not sure whether its the thumbnail that causing the vertical horizontal as well. regarding the html tags, i did edit but not yet upload them, still trying to figure the issue before uploading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tags are out of place. Notice how you open an `<a>` tag then a `<div>` and a `<span>` but you close the `</a>` before the `</span>` and `</div>`. HTML requires proper nesting so before you close the `</a>` you need to close every tag under it. Try using this code for the portfolio HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="portfolio">
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="Text 101 WebBuild V1/Text 101 WebBuild V1.html" target="_blank"> <img src="images/text101.png" class="image" width="100%">
                    <div class="imgDescription">
                        <h3 class="img-content"><strong>Text 101</strong></h3>
                         <span class="modal-button">
                             <img src="images/unity1.png" style="height:30px; width:30px;">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="landingPage.html" target="_blank"> <img src="images/myweb-app.png" alt="..." class="image" width="100%">
                    <div class="imgDescription">
                        <h3 class="img-content" style="left:95px;"><strong>MyWebsite App</strong></h3>
                        <span class="modal-button" style="left:145px">
                            <img src="images/webdev.png" style="height:30px; width:auto;">

                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#"> <img src="images/card3.jpg" alt="..." class="image" width="100%">
                    <div class="imgDescription">
                        <h3 class="img-content"></h3>
                        <span class="modal-button"></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: I also added `width="100%"` to the images for IE.

Comment: now its working fine in IE/firefox. thanks a lot. can you tell me though what was the issue that led the thumbnail to appear as in the screenshot

Comment: Your HTML was invalid and IE was rendering the images full size. By adding `width="100%"` it constrained the size of the images to the width of the parent container.

Comment: i see, thanks for pointing it out. one more thing I would like to ask @dotcomly do you know why is the background-image showing fine in all browsers in desktop but not in iphone browser, cheers

Comment: If you google `background image not showing on mobile` you will find a lot of things to try. My guess is your image is much larger than it needs to be: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html